# GWT TextColumn in CellTable with multiple lines

Tags: java, gwt, datagridtextcolumn

I'd like to display informations about a book in a CellTable in GWT. For example its content.
How can i create a TextColumn that displays that much text. Multiple lines or a scrollbar is what i'm looking for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your content is plain text, you can put it in TextColumn. It will wrap within a cell, unless some CSS prevents wrapping.

If you want to set a limit on how high a cell can be, add a CSS rule to this table:

```
.myTable tr {
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

If you have formatted text, you will need to create your own Cell by extending AbstractCell:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells